# How can I time prints consistently

Tags: python, video, frame-rate, timing

I'm training my python abilities by making a bunch of generally useless code and today I was attempting to print [Bad apple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i41KoE0iMYU) in the console using ASCII art as one does, I did everything just fine until I had to time the prints so they end in 3 minutes and 52 seconds maintaining a consistent framerate. I tried just adding a `time.sleep()`in between prints hoping it would all just magically work but obviously it didn't.

I customized a version of this git https://github.com/aypro-droid/image-to-ascii to transform frames to ASCII art and used https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ for transforming the video to frames

here is my code:

```
import time
frames = {}
#saving each .txt frame on a dict
for i in range(6955):
    f = open("Frames-to-Ascii/output/output{0}.txt".format(i), "rt")
    frames['t{0}'.format(i)] = f.read()
    f.close()
#start "trigger"
ini = input('start(type anything): ')
start = time.time()
#printing the 6954 frames from the dict
for x in range(6955):
    eval("print(frames['t{0}'])".format(x))
    #my attempt at timing
    time.sleep(0.015)
end = time.time()
#calculating how much time the prints took overall, should be about 211.2 seconds evenly distributed to all the "frames"
print(end-start)
```

frame example:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XumCX.png)

I'm attempting to time the prints perfectly to the video so I can later use it somewhere else, any tips?

Comment: You could calculate in advance what time you need to print each frame, then sleep for `time_to_print_next_frame - time_now`.

Comment: You said `time.sleep()` didn't work but what exactly didn't work? What was the output you got and how was it different from what you expected?

Comment: @kinshukdua The end time ended up being extremely inconsistent with about 20 seconds more or less than the expected result(211.2 seconds), now the code looks like this but it still has about 5 to 10 seconds from the expected result:
             

for x in range(6955):
    fstart = time.time()
    eval("print(frames['t{0}'])".format(x))
    fend = time.time()
    #second attempt at timing
    time.sleep(0.0253710095 - (fend - fstart))
end = time.time()
#calculating how much time the prints took overall
print(end-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you need to print the frames at a given constant rate?
If yes, then you need to evaluate the time used to print and then sleep for the delay minus the time to print. Something like:

```
for x in range(6955):
    start = time.time()
    print("hips")
    end = time.time()
    time.sleep(0.5-(end-start))
```

Thus the loop will take (approximatively) 0.5s to run. (Change the value accordingly to your needs).

Of course if a single print takes more time than the delay, you need to find another strategy: for example stepping over the next frame, etc.